# Multi tenant Azure B2C Login - how to get external user email address

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I am struggling to figure out how to configure Azure B2C for multi-tenant authentication, in particular getting access to the email address of a user that is logging in via an external Azure AD (we're interested in allowing our customers to log in either via a "Local Account" (email address, managed by B2C) or their own Azure AD).

A key part of the issue I am trying to result is the passing of the logged in users email address through to a REST endpoint where our application needs to do some things internally to inject additional application specific claims, which are used later on.  Apart from our REST endpoint receiving the email address, everything else is working.

I've got a "Common AAD" technical profile setup like this:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="Common-AAD">
    <DisplayName>Work Account</DisplayName>
    <Description>Login with your Work Account</Description>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
    <Metadata>
    <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
    <Item Key="client_id">my_client_id</Item>
    <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
    <Item Key="scope">openid email profile</Item>
    <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
    <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
    <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
    <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
    <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AADAppSecret"/>
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="upn" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

In the orchestration, I am instructing B2C to pass in a bunch of these claims to an application-hosted REST API so that we can do our internal processing:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-GetProfile-Dev">
    <DisplayName>Do some custom logic</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://the-endpoint.com</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="upnUserName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="upn" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" />

        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <!-- bunch of app specific claims -->
    </OutputClaims>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

However, I can never seem to get an email address, or anything that contains the email address of the logged in user passing through.

I've tried to track through the processing that's defined in the Custom Policy XML files, and it's challenging.  To be honest, I've been researching this and have tried adding all kinds of additional claims to outputs from various steps, but it's just not working for me.

Any help in detailing how to get the email address of a user logged in via an external Azure AD passed into a REST orchestration step would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

** Big Edit **

In response to Jas Suri, I have reset everything, applied the changes below as suggested, but am still not seeing this work.

Here's my **TrustFrameworkBase.xml**:
[TrustFrameworkBase.xml](https://gist.github.com/bgreen77/1d619923d2586501f8dd6ccc8ae2fb31)

Here's my **TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml**:
[TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml](https://gist.github.com/bgreen77/46167a690fd46c1d2a66304b60065d7b)

Here's my Relying Party (SignInSignUpMulti.xml) file:
[SignInSignUpMulti.xml](https://gist.github.com/bgreen77/1ad5cc424ecb879f2a10bd2cd549a842)

Now, looking at my scenarios:

When I sign in using a "local" account, I see this type of information pass through to my rest endpoint during the user journey:

```
{
    "objectId": "1e91bfba-17a1-43b6-a451-9896fc3c1061",
    "signInNames.emailAddress": "email@example.com",
    "displayName": "User DispName",
    "signInName": "email@example.com",
    "authenticationSource": "localAccountAuthentication"
}
```

That's *perfect*.  I can take this information and gather additional claims to return and all works exactly as I want.

When I sign in as an AD Account that's attached to **my** org, I get this:

```
{
    "objectId": "a_guid",
    "sub": "Not supported currently. Use oid claim.",
    "userPrincipalName": "cpim_a_guid@TENANT.onmicrosoft.com",
    "displayName": "ThisIs Correct",
    "upnUserName": "14218711-5dd1-4a81-8e04-77bd08298aaf",
    "alternativeSecurityId": "{\"type\":6,\"identityProvider\":\"https://login.microsoftonline.com/a_guid/v2.0\",\"key\":\"a_key\"}",
    "identityProvider": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/a_guid/v2.0",
    "authenticationSource": "socialIdpAuthentication"
}
```

I am missing an email (or the users Sign In) address.

And, the same happens when I try to sign in as an external AD:

```
{
    "objectId": "a_guid",
    "sub": "Not supported currently. Use oid claim.",
    "userPrincipalName": "cpim_a_guid@TENANT.onmicrosoft.com",
    "displayName": "ThisIs Correct",
    "upnUserName": "9c865de4-2898-4b18-998b-7fa151f6623d",
    "alternativeSecurityId": "{\"type\":6,\"identityProvider\":\"https://login.microsoftonline.com/a_guid/v2.0\",\"key\":\"a_key\"}",
    "identityProvider": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/a_guid/v2.0",
    "authenticationSource": "socialIdpAuthentication"
}
```

If I can work out how to pass through the email address or signin address, then I would be extremely happy.

Event during debugging, if I cause the user to be signed in anyway, I inspect the `User.Identity`, and while I see claims that my rest api is returning during the journey, I still don't have any claim that resembles the email address I am expecting (hoping) to see.
I can definitely work either way - an email address passed to the REST API, or the email address appearing in the final claim set that the application receives.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Azure AD, all users will come back with a unique_name claim, which is the UPN in their Azure AD. You could also rely on this. If you rely on the email claim from AAD, it will only be present if the user has an Exchange Online inbox. You also have to set it up as an optional Azure AD claim in the AAD Multi Tenant App registration.

Usually the UPN and Email are the same in an Azure AD. So in the [AAD technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga#add-a-claims-provider), you could add this output claim to capture the AAD UPN:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="aadUPN" PartnerClaimType="unique_name"/>
```

Then in the relying party secion, add this output claim:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="aadUPN" PartnerClaimType="UPNfromAAD"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The user not having an Exchange Online inbox makes sense now as to why I am not seeing it.  However, I added the additional output claims (I had to define them as well as claim types) but it's still not working.  Any other hints?

Comment: Youll need to share the policy files, that config should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks again - I've gone back and redone the files just in case debugging has screwed something up.  I've got the policy files (all three of them - the base, the extension and the relying party).  I was expecting (possibly incorrectly) to get a `unique_name` passed through to the REST API, but I am still not getting it (nor anything that looks like an email address once I hit the app proper)

Comment: `unique_name` is only in the [v1 tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens). I think its coming back as `preferred_username` as you're using v2 endpoint.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much for the assistance on this.  Switched to `preferred_username`, and **every** scenario that I am looking to support is working perfectly.